# What is the significance of the title "The painted veil"?

Tags: title, the-painted-veil

I just saw the movie but was not clear with the title significance. Is there any hidden meaning behind this title?

Answer (score 4):

The movie is **based on the 1925 novel** of the British author W. Somerset
Maugham. The title is taken from Percy Bysshe Shelley's sonnet which
begins "**Lift not the painted veil which those who live / Call Life**".

[This entry on answers.com offers an explanation](http://www.answers.com/Q/What_is_the_painted_veil_What_does_it_refer_to#ixzz1H30Yc5XY)

> **At a wedding, a veil is usually white, representing the innocence of
>   the person wearing it.  White is pure and has not yet been violated.
>   In the novel the veil is painted, which means that it is not an
>   innocent veil the characters are wearing.** Maugham used this concept to
>   show how all of society and the people living in it are tainted. The
>   only characters' in the novel that wear white, literally speaking, are
>   the nuns. In the novel one can read how they are all dressed
>   completely in white, except for a red cross on their chests. It is not
>   completely clear if the nuns are in fact wearing painted veils like
>   the rest of the characters. Nuns are supposed to be innocent and
>   saint-like, but maybe Maugham wants to say that just because they are
>   working for God does not mean that they are innocent. Indeed
>   Waddington questions their true nature.
>
> He says that he tried to make them leave, for their own safety, but
>   they would not, because they all want to die as martyrs (Maugham 101).
>   Another thing that can make one question the nuns' motives would be
>   their imposing Catholicism on the townspeople and the orphans. Do they
>   only help and take care of the children as long as they can spread
>   their religion? However, another interpretation is also possible.
>   Kitty believes that they are all saints, and they are the reason why
>   she decides to make a change in her life and give some back. The nuns
>   do help Kitty lift her own veil. They are the reason why she sees the
>   truth about her own shallow and selfish lifestyle.